# How to evaluate a variable with string value?

Tags: prolog

My code does perfect with numbers, but error with single quotation. I'm trying to write a `foldl` function.  When i do `foldl1(concat, ['a','b'], X)`, it reports like `"ERROR: Arithmetic: 'ab/0' is not a function".` what is the problem? prolog does not allow using `is` with string?

```
foldl1(P, [H], X) :-
    X is H.

foldl1(P, [H|T], X) :-
    foldl1(P, T, Y),
    call(P, H, Y, Z),
    X is Z.
```

Answer (score 2):

is/2 evaluates the *arithmetic expression* to the right, and *unifies* the result with the term to the left. Unification is also performed against the *head*' arguments, so you can write a simplified foldl1/3 like

```
foldl1(_, [H], H).
foldl1(P, [H|T], Z) :-
    foldl1(P, T, Y),
    call(P, H, Y, Z).
```

test:

```
?- foldl1(plus,[1,2,3],R).
R = 6 ;
false.

?- foldl1(concat,[1,2,3],R).
R = '123' ;
false.
```

I would place a cut after the recursion base, since `[H]` and `[H|T]` where `T=[]` overlap, to avoid any last call - that would anyway fail - on eventual backtracking, like the redo induced by me, inputting `;` after the expected first answer while the interpreter waits for my choices.
After the cut (hope you can easily spot where to place it) we get:

```
?- foldl1(plus,[1,2,3],R).
R = 6.

?- foldl1(concat,[1,2,3],R).
R = '123'.
```

Now the interpreter 'knows' there are no more answers after the first...

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to implement a `foldl1/3` predicate using first-argument indexing to avoid spurious choice-points without cuts and that is also tail-recursive. From the Logtalk library `meta` object:

```
:- meta_predicate(foldl1(3, *, *)).
foldl1(Closure, [Head| Tail], Result) :-
    fold_left_(Tail, Closure, Head, Result).

fold_left_([], _, Result, Result).
fold_left_([Arg| Args], Closure, Acc, Result) :-
    call(Closure, Acc, Arg, Acc2),
    fold_left_(Args, Closure, Acc2, Result).
```

Sample calls:

```
?- meta::foldl1(plus,[1,2,3],R).
R = 6.

?- meta::foldl1(concat,[1,2,3],R).
R = '123'.
```